# Datatable warning, Ajax error message. Failed to load resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

Im working on a project, where you can add employees and add improvement proposals. Employee function is all good, but when I click on the add improvement proposals, it get this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

When I go into inspect on chrome the error message is:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

ps.Forslag means proposal/suggestion
Here is my forslag.js file:

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
   loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "Admin/Forslag/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "nyttForslag", "width": "15%" },
        ]
    });
}
```

...............................

Comment: That just means there is no service at the relative location of Admin/Forslag/GetAll. You need to verify or fix the route to your controller.

Comment: Thank you! Can I write to you on discord Crowcoder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 404(not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416702/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-404not-found)